# Convert the Bessel equation $x^{2}y''+xy'+(\lambda x^{2}-\alpha^{2})y=0$ to integral equation.

Tags: bessel-functions, integral-equations

Convert the Bessel equation $x^{2}y''+xy'+(\lambda x^{2}-\alpha^{2})y=0$ to integral equation, where $0<x<1,$ $y (x)$ is bounded as $x\to 0$, $y(1)=0$, where $\alpha>0. $
Please give some hint to solve this.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, but I'd suggest taking the Laplace transform.

Comment: How can we solve it using Green's function. ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first divide the ODE by $x$ in order to rewrite it in the form of a Sturm-Liouville equation:
$$
xy''+y'+\left(\lambda x-\frac{\alpha^2}{x}\right)y=0
\implies (xy')'-\frac{\alpha^2}{x}y=-\lambda xy. \tag{1}
$$
Then, we can formally rewrite $(1)$ as
$$
y(x)=-\lambda\int_0^1G(x,s)sy(s)\,ds, \tag{2}
$$
where $G(x,s)$ is the solution to
$$
\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)-\frac{\alpha^2}{x}\right]G(x,s)=\delta(x-s). \tag{3}
$$
If $x\neq s$, Eq. $(3)$ reduces to a Cauchy-Euler equation, which has as general solution the function  $f(x)=c_1x^{\alpha}+c_2x^{-\alpha}$. Therefore, imposing the conditions $G(0,s)<\infty$ and $G(1,s)=0$, we have
$$
G(x,s)=\begin{cases}
A_sx^{\alpha}&\text{if $x<s$}, \\
B_s(x^{\alpha}-x^{-\alpha})&\text{if $x>s$}.
\end{cases} \tag{4}
$$
To determine the coefficients $A_s$ and $B_s$, we apply the [additional conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Green%27s_functions_for_solving_inhomogeneous_boundary_value_problems) $G(s+0,s)=G(s-0,s)$ and $s(\partial_xG(s+0,s)-\partial_xG(s-0,s))=1$. The final result for $G(x,s)$ is
$$
G(x,s)=\frac{1}{2\alpha}\times\begin{cases}
(s^{\alpha}-s^{-\alpha})x^{\alpha}&\text{if $x<s$}, \\
(x^{\alpha}-x^{-\alpha})s^{\alpha}&\text{if $x>s$}.
\end{cases} \tag{5}
$$
The integral equation $(2)$, with $G(x,s)$ given by $(5)$, is equivalent to the ODE $(1)$ in the interval $[0,1]$ with the conditions $y(0)<\infty$ and $y(1)=0$.